error: expected ';', identifier or '(' before 'int' in header file
I keep getting the error in the title with the line extern int inp_arr[SIZE];. This is the full header file, queue.h
#ifndef SIZE
#define SIZE    4
#endif

#ifndef QUEUE_H    
#define QUEUE_H

extern int inp_arr[SIZE];   
extern int rear;
extern int front;

void enqueue(int insert_item);
void dequeue(void);
void output_queue(void);
int peek(void);

#endif  // QUEUE_H   


I have tried adding the header guards for it as well as just having the extern declerations within the QUEUE_H header guards like so:
#ifndef SIZE
#define SIZE 4  
#endif

#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

extern int inp_arr[4];
extern int rear;
extern int front;

#endif  // QUEUE_H

void enqueue(int insert_item);
void dequeue(void);
void output_queue(void);
int peek(void);

but still got an error on line 8 as well, which is the line I keep getting this error on:
queue.h:8:8: error: expected ';', identifier or '(' before 'int'

I also initialised the extern variables inside of queue.c:
#include "queue.h"

int inp_arr[SIZE];
int rear = -1;
int front = -1;

I slightly remeber changing something inside of a C file that used this header file (and compiled with queue.c) which then caused this issue, but I cannot remeber what it was. For context, I am trying to make a simple round robin scheduling program for the Rasberry Pi Pico W and am uploading + compiling using the VSCode extension with it.

Check the line in your source file right before you include the header.

You can't reproduce the error with the code you show.  Neither can we.  Please read about how to create an MCVE (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example
— or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE (Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example
— the same idea by a different name).

As an aside, you should normally place all the content of the header inside the header guards — the #ifndef SIZE / #define SIZE 4 / #endif stanza should be between #define QUEUE_H and #endif // QUEUE_H — and before SIZE is used.  The 4 in extern int inp_arr[4]; should probably be SIZE.

I agree with @dbush, the error seems to what is processed just before, and if the line before including "queue.h" is also a #include, you have to check the previously included file, in particular the end.

One way to troubleshoot strange syntax error like this is to 1) comment out all standard lib headers 2) run the compiler in pre-processor mode (gcc queue.c -E) then peek at the output. You'll now see the .c file source preprocessed and merged with every header you included and that way it is much easier to spot the bug.

very little of what you are showing is relevant to the problem, and none of what you are additionally doing is relevant to the problem.  You have some C files somewhere, which contain #include "queue.h".  The error you are receiving is happening while trying to compile one of those C files. SHOW US THAT FILE.  (Or at least the top page of it.)

The problem is probably in the file where you #include <queue.h> itself.   This is one of the reasons we request you to post a complete and verifiable example.  I don't see any error in queue.h, mostly because you forgot to finish some declaration before including it.
